# How do I disable notifications in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, notifications

I've found that Outlook notifications are quite a pain and I've tried to disable them but I can't find a setting anywhere. Does anyone know how to disable the calendar notifications (separate windows that shows up) on Office 365 installed locally on Mac OS 10.13 and Windows 10 (Outlook for Mac v16.16 and Outlook 2016 respectively)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why instructions like this aren't usable: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-outlook-calendar-reminders

Answer (score 1):

As per Outlook for Mac, you can turn off all reminders by clicking Turn Off Reminders on the Outlook menu. For more details, check the following MS article:

[Turn off reminders and reminder sounds in Outlook for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-reminders-and-reminder-sounds-in-outlook-for-mac-b21ad183-efbe-431d-b161-8425b38a569d)

As regards to Outlook for Windows, you may refer to the instructions mentioned in the link shared by Appleoffity.

Answer (score 0):

If you've having trouble disabling Outlook's notification sounds - On a Mac these can be disabled per app from **System Preferences->Notifications**.

If you're *still* getting notification sounds make sure you're not logged into outlook.com in a web browser tab somewhere - it has it's own sound notification preferences which need to be silenced (Settings->General->Notifications).